# Person detection with counter display using OpenCV, and YOLOv5

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, yolov5

I'm new to computer vision and I wanted to create something that detects people and at the same time displays the counter of the people detected from a live feed camera source or a webcam for example.

This is my code.

```
import cv2
import torch
import torchvision


model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX


person_count = 0

while True:

    _, frame = camera.read()


    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 640))
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame = torch.tensor(frame).permute(2, 0, 1)
    frame = frame.unsqueeze(0)

    output = model(frame)[0]


    boxes = output[0]['boxes'] 
    labels = output[0]['labels']


    for box, label in zip(boxes, labels):

        if label == 0:
            person_count += 1


        cv2.rectangle(frame, (box[0], box[1]), (box[2], box[3]), (255, 0, 0), 2)


    cv2.putText(frame, f"Person count: {person_count}", (10, 50), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)


    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)


    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However I encountered some problem in this code "boxes = output[0]['boxes']"
the error is this     boxes = output['boxes']
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1.

I need help figuring out how to make this work. I would appreciate any ideas thanks!

I have not tried anything however i'm stuck at this for hours and I just wanted to make this program work.

Comment: why you dont use directly the `output`

Comment: output = model(frame)